# How to read a data frame in jsonlite

Tags: r, jsonlite

I am trying to read a data frame in jsonlite. I have a json file (which is made from an html code from a newspaper article , and structured in some variables: title, body, comments), and I managed to rename it.

```
install.packages("jsonlite")
library("jsonlite")
article1 <- fromJSON("/Users/eva/Desktop/bdk.blufaerdighed.html.json")
```

I now want to "see" the content of my file (I want to see the text belonging to the variables; title, body, comments etc.), but I don't know which function to use.

my json file looks like this:

> { "author":"Ulla Gunge", "body":"De har »opført sig blufærdighedskrænkende«. I en uge har to otteårige drenge derfor været bortvist fra deres skole i Horsens.", "comments":[], "subtitle":"To otteårige drenge er blevet bortvist fra deres skole for at have vist deres tissemænd til en pige. Men den slags er helt normalt i den alder, fortæller forsker i voksnes syn på børns seksualitet, doktorlege og pædofilifrygt.", "title":"Blufærdighed i børnehøjde" }

Comment: Would you give an example of the data set

Comment: Please don't add it as a comment. Edit your question.

Comment: my json file looks like this :-) I would like to know how to structure my variables and put them into rows and columns :D

Answer (score 1):

To see those fields you just print them

```
article1$title
article1$body
article1$comments
```

Answer (score 0):

Data frame structure is a list of vectors of equal length. The `comment` field in your json has length 0. You can see this for example by typing:

```
sapply(article1, length)
#   author     body comments subtitle    title 
#        1        1        0        1        1
```

If you can change the json from `"comments":[]` to `"comments":["NA"]` it is possible to get the data frame directly with `fromJSON` function by using `simplifyDataFrame` attribute.

Or you could change the list with `article1$comments <- NA` and get the data frame with:

```
as.data.frame(article1)
```